# Qt : Moving Items in a QListView with Animations without qml

Tags: qt, delegates, qlistview

I am working on a QListView to provide a functionality that animates the movement of items in the listView. For example :

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
```

If i click on item4 and move/drag up then then each item should shift one position down with animation and the current position should be empty until the item is dropped.

Is there any way to implement this without using qml. I have a thought of implementing this with QPropertyAnimation or QTimeLine, but I need the specific co-ordinates/position of the items in the list. I have also implemented a delegate using QStyledItemDelegate where in the paintEvent I can get the coordinates of each item using option.rect.